# Extracting a vector from a matrix using vector of column indices

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a matrix

```
A = [ 5  2
      2  3
     -4  7 ];
```

and a vector `v = [1 2 1]`. I want extract the vector `B` from `A` using the columns indexed by `v`. That is, `B` should look like

```
B = [ 5
      3
     -4 ];
```

I tried `B = A(:,v)` but that didn't work. Any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the column subscripts. Generate the row subscripts and use [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to get linear indices to [retrieve](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) desired elements of `A`.

```
B = A(sub2ind(size(A),1:numel(v),v))
```

Comment: I found a slightly faster implementation for 2D taking advantage of the fact that `A(2,2)` can be indexed using `A(5)`. We can write `B = A((1:numel(v))+(v-1)*size(A,1))`.